# How to read images via xml using php?

Tags: php, xml, image

I have xml file which contain an image tag which represent a team image.
I use the following to read the xml file:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/feeds/team_id');
```

I pass the link to a function to parse it .
The xml pattern like this:

```
<teams>
<team id="9260" is_national_team="False">
<name>Manchester United</name>
<fullname/>
<country>England</country>
<founded>1878</founded>
<leagues></leagues>
<venue_name>Old Trafford</venue_name>
<image>
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
</image>
</team>
</teams>
```

How can I parse the image i can not understand what is this codes ? is it some kind of codeing the image? and how to decode it? or it is a kind of compressing need to be uncompressed?

Comment: Doesn't look like a base64 encoding, I think you need to ask the creator of the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image is base64 encoded. just put the code inside the image src tag

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,[insert base64 string here!!!]">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UGBq8/